# IntelliJ ignoring exclude directives in submodule pom.xml files

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea

I've got a spring project deploying to amazon that builds fine using STS.

The project consists of a top level pom.xml file that references a number of submodules that each contains their own pom.xml file

Inside the pom.xml files in the submodules there are various "exclude" directives which will prevent the compilation of various files and paths.

STS respects these exclude directives and does not attempt to compile the files. IntelliJ does not.

When I import the project into itellij I am selecting the top level pom.xml file for import, then telling intellij to import recursively.

I'm sure I am doing something wrong, but can't figure out what that is yet.